# ActiveRecord finding existing table indexes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am writing a migration generator for a plugin I am writing and I need to to be able to find what unique indexes a table has so I can modify existing unique indexes to become a composite unique index.  I have been trying to find a way to access what indexes a table has with ActiveRecord.  I have only been able to find ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::indexes method, but unfortunately this is only available for the PosgreSQLAdapter.  I need to be able to support the other major databases.

I first grepping the schema.rb file to find the indexes, this worked at first, but I soon realized this was a bad strategy.

I was thinking that if ActiveRecord does not provide a means to be able to do this for multiple database adapters, I may be able to write adapter specific queries to retrieve the index information from a table.  If I need to resort to this method what would be a good way to determine the adapter in use?

If someone knows of a way to get ActiveRecord to list table index information that would be ideal.

Comment: The only way I can think to do this right now is with the help of 
    ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump

The problem is that this dumps the current schema to $stdout and I do not know how to capture that and convert the output into a string.  If I knew that, I would be able to use the code from my first approach of reading schema.rb.  Anyone know how to capture $stdout for something that was wrote in a block?
For example this does not work:
    schema_str = IO::open(2) { ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump }.read

Comment: I realize this question is ancient, but I had the exact same issue trying to get SchemaDumper to dump to a string. I finally found the answer, and I'll post it in case anyone else has this issue: `schema_rb_as_string = ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, StringIO.new).string`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This works with MySQL, SQLite3, and Postgres:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
    puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(table).inspect
end
```

But I think it only gives you the indexes you specifically created.

Also, to find out which adapter is in use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class
```

Comment: Here is the link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-indexes

Comment: "But I think it only gives you the indexes you specifically created." So don't panic if you don't see an index on your table's primary key; it's (probably) there, just not included in this list.

Answer (score 32):

Just an update for cleaner inspection. As I had many tables I was finding it difficult to search for specific stuffs.

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  indexes = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(table)
  if indexes.length > 0
    puts "====>  #{table} <===="
    indexes.each do |ind|
      puts "----> #{ind.name}"
    end
    puts "====>  #{table} <===="
    2.times{ puts ''}
  end
end
```

This will be of quick setup.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Much cleaner than the accepted response.

Comment: Append `&& nil` to the final end to silence all table data `each` returns.

Answer (score 25):

If you just want to see all the indexes for a particular table you can do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes('my_table_name').map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you have multiple DBs and the proposed `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(table).inspect` doesn't work because it is pointing to other DBs. You can do this in your rails console.

- Find the model you care, let's say "User"
- User.connection.indexes("users").inspect
- profit