# Rails/ActiveRecord method to check an SQL(mysql to be specific) table index

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any Rails command/method to list the indexes of an SQL table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with MySQL, SQLite3, and Postgres:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
    puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(table).inspect
end`

Already answered here [ActiveRecord finding existing table indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683948/activerecord-finding-existing-table-indexes)

The following works with **[Show All Indexes in Your table - Oracle DB](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/oracle/Show-All-Indexes-in-Your-Schema.html)** for specific table wise finding the indexes defined. It works for me.

`ModelName.find_by_sql("SELECT index_name, table_name, uniqueness FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'")`

You can try this for MYSQL. I have not tested this one, you can confirm if it works.

`ModelName.find_by_sql("SHOW INDEX FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")`