# how to find missing indices in mysql using rspec?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, sequel

I need to identify missing indices in mysql before deploy to production. For example, analyze rspec test.
My stack:

- sinatra
- sequel gem
- mysql

It is preferable ORM-agnostic solution or for sequel ORM
Is it exist?

Comment: What's your definition of "missing indices"? Specified in your migration file but missing on the DB? Recommended indices based on your queries? Or something else?

Comment: Additionally - this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683948/activerecord-finding-existing-table-indexes

Comment: unless your test environment has an amount of data similar to that in your production environment -- there will be no way to tell from running tests where your application needs additional indices.

Comment: rspec does not have the ability to determine whether queries can be optimized by using indexes. If you have performance problems with your queries, you can use `explain` to see what indexes are being used. You can also look at the SQL for the query and determine what indexes are likely to improve performance. Run some benchmarks, then try some indexes and see if performance has improved.

Comment: I linked to another question that isn't exactly the same as yours, since it's not specifically about rspec. However, the answers are virtually the same. It's a nontrivial problem for any tool to automatically decide which indexes you need, and it would have a high rate of false results (both failing to detect a need for an index, and also recommending an index that is not needed).